# Known Bug in Python Pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

Given the following code:

```
import pickle

class Test:
    d = {}    

    def func(self):
        self.d['x'] = 'y'

test = Test()
test.func()
pickle.dump(test, open('test.p', 'wb'))

%reset

import pickle
class Test:
    d = {}    

    def func(self):
        self.d['x'] = 'y'


print(pickle.load(open('test.p', 'rb')).d)
```

I would expect the output

```
y
y
```

However, the actual output is

```
y
{}
```

Is this a known bug or am I misunderstanding something?

I am using **Miniconda Python 3.5.2** on *Windows*.

Comment: I would not expect the output that you expect. `self.d` is a class variable. Pickle serializes objects, not classes.

Comment: Any time you're wondering whether there's a bug in a Python standard library module, you can generally assume that the answer is "no, you're just doing something wrong."

Comment: the `.d` is not specific to the object you pickled, why would you expect it to be pickled along with the object?

Comment: In that case, either [edit] this question and add your new program, or ask a new question. Perhaps there is another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

> ... when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled.

The behavior you see is documented and not in error.